# after creating SEO friendly url menu link also change

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am writing seo url for my website. in homepage everything is fine with all links in menu. after click http://www.example.com/article/article-name i see the content but my menu url also change for that page like www.example.com/article/menuoption1 but 
actual url is www.example.com/menuoption1 . how i can solve this issue and any other changes required in my code.please help

```
Options +FollowSymLinks   
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^article/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+) article.php?article=$1 [NC,L]



RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: When you click the link it rewrites or the link itself changed? If the click make the path absolute. So `href="/menuoption1"` instead of `href="menuoption1"`

Comment: yes its works but same time /article  are include in all links in  http://www.example.com/article/article-name page

Comment: Thank you so much..problem solved

Comment: thank you for more information. the problem is solve with /menuoption1. feeling great to here with you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`href="menuoption1"` is a relative path meaning it will point the user to the current directory they are on.

So if on `/article`. The user will get

```
/article/menuoption1
```

to resolve that make it absolute:

```
href="/menuoption1"
```

This way that link when on any page will go back to the root of the domain `/`.